# What does this sentence mean ? "You know you're from Texas when you go back to visit and the first stop on your list is Whataburger"

Tags: sentence, slang

I see this sentence but I don't really understand it.
What is the main mean of it ?

You know you're from Texas when you go back to visit and the first stop on your list is Whataburger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whataburger is a fast food restaurant, like McDonalds or Burger King. It is big in the southern states. This sentence is describing how someone from Texas might feel when returning/visiting home (Texas) after living/visiting somewhere else, specifically a geographical area that lacks a Whataburger fast food restaurant.

Comment: indeed, it is even more appropos, because Whatburger has its HQ in the city of San Antonio, Texas.

Comment: @Clare you're thinking of HEB. Whataburger started in Corpus.

Comment: @jlovegren Um, no. The HQ is in SA. It used to be in CC. (I didnt say it started in SA.)
300 Concord Plaza Dr.
San Antonio, TX 78216
Phone: 210-476-6000
Mailing Address
PO Box 791990
San Antonio, TX 78279

Comment: @Clare oh, I forgot. we are on the internet.